# Mulitples images upload using carrierwave & cloudinary Got only 1 item stored in my Json array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, carrierwave

I got no error message and everything seems to be good but as you can see as result the json column Images of Country model store only le last image of uploaded files.
I cant understand why is not working.

Here's my **Country** model

```html
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
  serialize :images, JSON
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_name, :against => [:name]

end
```

Here is my ActiveAdmin model **Country**

```html
ActiveAdmin.register Country do
    permit_params :name, :description, :photo, :photo_cache, :address, :full_description, :best_period, :country, :latitude, :longitude, {images: []}

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :name
    column :description
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

      form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
      f.inputs "Identity" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
      f.input :description
      f.input :full_description
      f.input :best_period
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**I cant understand why there's only one item store in my images column**

here's the console Logs

```html
Started POST "/admin/countries" for ::1 at 2017-10-28 19:30:48 +0200
Processing by Admin::CountriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JUC+1egeOmL+fkyTMD8gjcGfEp6HCr8aY9ZG5SsV+ZSCOQq8gVweSXrva++8Bqh+UM42aVBhx1Oiib8fzFv+Jg==", "country"=>{"name"=>"South Africa", "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faa611a4088 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ql/2q1360r91vbbh0578gwtwgyc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171028-849-18lgegy.jpg>, @original_filename="Afrique_du_sud - couverture.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"country[images][]\"; filename=\"Afrique_du_sud - couverture.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faa611a4060 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ql/2q1360r91vbbh0578gwtwgyc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171028-849-1w04ibh.jpg>, @original_filename="Afrique_du_sud - photo1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"country[images][]\"; filename=\"Afrique_du_sud - photo1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faa611c76f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ql/2q1360r91vbbh0578gwtwgyc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171028-849-11drf6n.jpg>, @original_filename="Afrique_du_sud - photo2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"country[images][]\"; filename=\"Afrique_du_sud - photo2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faa611c7588 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ql/2q1360r91vbbh0578gwtwgyc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171028-849-1k00ol1.jpg>, @original_filename="Afrique_du_sud - photo3.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"country[images][]\"; filename=\"Afrique_du_sud - photo3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "description"=>"Description", "full_description"=>"Full description", "best_period"=>"best period"}, "commit"=>"Create Country"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "countries" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name", "description", "full_description", "best_period", "images") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2017-10-28 17:30:48 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-10-28 17:30:48 UTC], ["name", "South Africa"], ["description", "Description"], ["full_description", "Full description"], ["best_period", "best period"], ["images", "\"[\\\"gmfhubfuzll8v8pjhjfv.jpg\\\",\\\"biyroewakmitexsphpup.jpg\\\",\\\"elmmtycn5aasd42xtvdr.jpg\\\",\\\"cqjsdccgrelaedanklve.jpg\\\"]\""]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "countries" SET "images" = '"\"image/upload/v1509211850/gmfhubfuzll8v8pjhjfv.jpg\""' WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  [["id", 80]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "countries" SET "images" = '"\"image/upload/v1509211854/biyroewakmitexsphpup.jpg\""' WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  [["id", 80]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "countries" SET "images" = '"\"image/upload/v1509211857/elmmtycn5aasd42xtvdr.jpg\""' WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  [["id", 80]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "countries" SET "images" = '"\"image/upload/v1509211859/cqjsdccgrelaedanklve.jpg\""' WHERE "countries"."id" = $1  [["id", 80]]
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/countries/80
Completed 302 Found in 12112ms (ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

**RESULT**

```html
[5] pry(main)> Country.first.images.length
  Country Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 1
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1653?

Comment: Yes I already did it